# Terminal OS X Error when using Python

Tags: macos, terminal

Hey, I'm trying to learn how to program so I've installed the latest version of Python and I've been following the Byte of Python tutorial. I'm using Textwrangler I've only gotten as far as the simple "Hello World" intro and I'm already having a problem. I type out the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#Filename: helloworld.py

print('Hello World')
```

and save it to my desktop as helloworld.py. I then go into terminal and type "python3 helloworld.py" and I get the following error message:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'helloworld.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I was hoping someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong. If I choose to run the script from Textwrangler it operates just fine however I'm not able to access it from the Terminal. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be in the same directory in the terminal that you saved the file in or you need to specify the full directory on the command line:

```
cd /path/to/directory
python3 helloworld.py
```

or

```
python3 /path/to/directory/helloworld.py
```

What directory did you save the file to?

Comment: Awesome thank you so much I think I understand how it works now. I just had to specify that it was in /users/username/desktop python3 helloworld.py. Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

just save your .py file to a folder on your desktop and then you should be able to right click it and at the bottom of the options that come up just press new terminal at folder. I had the same problem as you and this worked for me.